# Sidekiq jobs store references to the class constant and what else? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Say I have a job that fires off in a separate thread like this:

```
TaxCalculator.perform_async({ user_id: user.id, description: 'test description', count: 1 })
```

Say the actual class is something like:

```
class TaxCalculator
  def perform(args)
      user = User.find(args['user_id'])
      description = args['description']
      #some stuff goes on here
  end
end
```

Say the queue is quite long. Some things happen and perhaps code changes and deploys are made. When the job finally fires, what references are needed. If the class name changes to something else like to say `Namespace::TaxCalculator`, will the job fail? What kind of reference is still in a Sidekiq job? the arguments? The id? The name of the class?

Comment: The typical recommendation is to send SIGUSR1 to the Sidekiq daemon to tell it to stop accepting new work, let it finish running all the jobs in the queue, redeploy your code with these types of changes, send SIGTERM to kill the daemon, and restart it. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#overview

Answer (score 4):

With changes in your structure you can use old constant as a link to new, for example:

`TaxCalculator = Namespace::TaxCalculator`

... and with the next update you can remove this link because all the jobs was finished.

Comment: Exactly, Sidekiq stores the class name so if you change it, you need to keep the old class name until all old jobs have been processed.